# Make part of SVG static when scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, d3.js

I am trying to make an SVG g tag static and do not move when the user scrolls the page up and down. Something similar to having an iframe in the page.

Here is an example

```
<svg>
   <g>
     <text x="0" y="0">hello</text>
   </g>
</svg>
```

The code is much larger than this and requires the user to scroll to view the entire svg. I am trying to make the  tag above static and not move when the user scrolls.

Any ideas please?

Comment: You state the code is much larger, can you provide a JSFiddle or something will the entire problem so we can view the full problem?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge the individual groups inside an SVG do not take positioning contexts as they are not independent of the SVG. So this is not possible given your specific layout. You could individualise this specific group to a separate SVG which could then be positioned though.

Comment: what i would do is create an additional svg element to contain the g, and use css to set its position to fixed. obviously you could track the user's scroll position and use js to change the positions of the svg elements themselves but that seems overly complicated

Comment: You would need to either use danyamachine's approach, or you could use javascript to adjust the group's position on an onscroll event.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments/suggestions. I went with separate svgs and it seems to be working to an extent. The header is now fixed while the other svg scrolls. One other issues I have is when I scroll the second svg up, it gets behind the first svg and mix together. How do I make it so it does not get behind the first svg, like making the first svg non-transparent?

Comment: I figured it out!. I added a rect before the g tag and it worked very well!